# Take a screenshot of a area in xfce?

Tags: xfce

Is possible to take an screenshot of just area of my desktop using xfce? I have tried uisng Shift+Print screen, but doesn't work..

Im running 4.10 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [screenshot](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/applications/xfce4-screenshooter), the Xfce4 Screenshooter is part of the [xfce-Goodies](http://goodies.xfce.org/). It can capture areas as well as fullscreen and application windows.

Comment: Note that by default, the "Print Screen" key on keyboard is configured as `xfce4-screenshooter -f`, where `-f` means fullscreen, bypassing the select region, active window or fullscreen options. Removing the `-f` on the default config makes the trick.

Comment: On top of @Jan answer, you need to configure Shift+Print shortcut and run the `xfce4-screenshooter` with the `-r` param.
http://i.imgur.com/iLiUZHf.png

Comment: I'm using a `Manjaro 20.1 Xfce4` standard installation and there `Ctrl-Shift-Print` shortcuts by default to `make screenshot of user specific area`  (the one with the cross-hair pointer), very helpful in my eyes

Comment: Note: I was able to install on debian using apt install xfce4-goodies

Comment: In Xubuntu XFCE 20.04, I found Shift+Print to be the default in the Settings for Keyboard for taking a screenshot by region. Here are all of the screenshot-related defaults as I see them from my installation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap0Ov.png